# handlebar.js helpers with asynchronous data

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, promise

I wonder how to work with sync data and handlebar helpers. I want to load cms messages to a single page application and I tried out following method and could not able to achieve it.

Please see following code.

```
    function loadCmsMessage(key) {

    var cms = {
            "msg.001": "Hello {0} {1}"
        };

        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        setTimeout(function () {
            var msg = cms[key];
            deferred.resolve(msg);
        }, 1000);

        return deferred.promise();
    }

Handlebars.registerHelper('cms', function (key, arr) {

    var promise = loadCmsMessage(key);

    promise.done(function (str) {
        str = Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(str);

        if ($.isArray(arr)) {
            $.each(arr, function (i) {
                var safeStr = Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(arr[i]);
                str = str.replace("{" + i + "}", safeStr);
            });
        }

        var result = '<span class="cms-data">' + str + '</span>';

        return new Handlebars.SafeString(result);
    });

});

$(document).ready(function () {
    var template = Handlebars.compile($("#myTemplate").html());
    $("#wrap").html(template({
        "person": ['Jane', 'Fonda']
    }));
});
```

Comment: Handlebars template functions generate a string which are immutable in javascript. You should make your ajax call and perhaps regenerate the template when the content comes in as its out of scope for handlebars. Some frameworks provide means of this functionality such as ember and angular I believe

Comment: I am using Marionette on top of Backbone.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The `return` statement is at the inner function of the Promise. Handlebars helpers don't allow asynchronousness.